# Osmdroid - custom offline tile source change location

Tags: android, osmdroid

I am using this code for displaying offline Osmdroid map tiles. Problem is, I have stored my tiles in location /sdcard/emulated0/0/. It there any way how to pass it into XYTileSource?

Thx

```
    myMapView.setTileSource  (new XYTileSource ("Mapnik", ResourceProxy.string.offline_mode, 13, 17, 512, ".png", "http://127.0.0.1"))
```

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this in the end? I would also like to be able to change the location of my tilesource