# OSMdroid - unable to load offline map tiles from custom location

Tags: android, offline, osmdroid

I have looked around and can't find an answer to what I hope is quite a simple thing to achieve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759654/osmdroid-custom-offline-tile-source-change-locationhttp://) question seemed similar but has no replies!  So the problem is this; I have my offline map tiles on the android device here:

```
/sdcard/application-name/uuid/tiles
```

and I have set the OSM cache like so:

```
File applicationDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), File.separator + "application-name" + File.separator + "uuid" + File.separator);
OpenStreetMapTileProviderConstants.setCachePath(applicationDir.getAbsolutePath());
```

I then set up the TileSource:

```
ITileSource tileSource = new XYTileSource ("tiles", 0, 18, 256, ".png", new String[]{});
```

and the TileProvider:

```
tileProvider = new MapTileProviderBasic(getActivity());
tileProvider.setTileSource(tileSource);
```

When I run my app, I get a succession of these:

```
Error downloading MapTile: /15/16000/9960
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0
at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:175)
at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.OnlineTileSourceBase.getBaseUrl(OnlineTileSourceBase.java:33)
at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.XYTileSource.getTileURLString(XYTileSource.java:19)
at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileDownloader$TileLoader.loadTile(MapTileDownloader.java:171)
at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileModuleProviderBase$TileLoader.run(MapTileModuleProviderBase.java:291)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Presumably because the local tiles aren't found and the MapTileProviderBasic ultimately falls to the MapTileDownloader and it barfs because there are no online tiles.

Any suggestions gratefully received!
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried writing the path yourself to see what happens?

Comment: I don't think the path is the problem, when I hardcoded it, it still failed.  I think the problem lies with the Source or the Provider.

Comment: I'll come back to you in a couple hours if I see anything, will have to compare with my code because I feel mine wasn't much different from yours.

Comment: Thanks @M.Haché, have you had a look at your code?

Comment: Try setting up an sample URL on your tilesource. Instead of `ITileSource tileSource = new XYTileSource ("tiles", 0, 18, 256, ".png", new String[]{});` try `ITileSource tileSource = new XYTileSource ("tiles", 0, 18, 256, ".png", new String[]{"http://i.dont.care.org/"});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I eventually sorted this out by using the OSMDroid default location on the device

```
/sdcard/osmdroid/uuid/tiles
```

and set the tile source like so

```
ITileSource tileSource = new XYTileSource(uuid, 0, 17, 256, ".png", new String[0]);
```

osmdroid looks inside the directory uuid for a subdirectory called 'tiles', although the documentation kind of tells you this, it's not very explicit.  I think you could probably use any location on the sdcard using this approach, I just decided to use the simplest solution.

Comment: What will happen if you don't have a sdcard in your device?

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue on a device which does not have a default "uuid" folder (8" Samsung Tab 4) when trying to use a MOBAC-generated .zip file. I found a solution at the link below, but the gist is this:

1. Unzip the MOBAC-generated .zip file, and re-zip only the directory which contains tile zoom-level subdirectories (e.g., the ones labeled "10", "11", etc.)
2. Place the new zip in the `osmdroid` directory. NOT in `osmdroid\tiles\`.
3. In your code, reference the specific `TileSourceFactory` sub-type for the source which you used to generate the atlas. This worked for me (when using the OpenStreetMap public transport layer): `map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.PUBLIC_TRANSPORT);`

This could be used in conjunction with a check to see if the device has a data connection:

```
// Check for data connection and use offline map if necessary
    if (Main.deviceIsOnline()) {
        map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
        //map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.USGS_SAT);
        //map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.USGS_TOPO);
    } else {
        map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.PUBLIC_TRANSPORT);
    }
```

Here is the link:

https://mobiledevstories.wordpress.com/2014/02/27/osmdroid-mobile-atlas-creator-tutorial/